# jQuery Validtion - Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to validate a field.

Validation Rule:  Multiple Values can be entered in text box in format of 1,2,3,4...
                  Range (1 to 7) and are only separated by ','.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as something to keep for later, there is an [awesome website for testing and tweaking regular expressions](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) that a colleague forwarded to me.

I have a few answers for you, this allows no spaces ("1,2,3,4,5,6,7"):

```
^[1-7]$|^([1-7],)+[1-7]$
```

This allows arbitrary spacing between a comma and the next number ("1, 2,   3"):

```
^[1-7]$|^([1-7],\s*)+[1-7]$
```

This allows arbitrary spacing as long as it's number, comma, number etc. (" 1 , 2, 3  ,4"):

```
^[1-7]$|^(\s*[1-7]+\s*,\s*)+[1-7]$
```

I'm no expert, there are probably more concise ways to do this. That's the Regex part. For jQuery validation (assuming you haven't already) check out "bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/" (sorry can't post more than one link due to reputation). Use it all the time and it's awesome and pretty easy.